# react-apollo cannot read property map of undefined

Tags: reactjs, graphql

fellow hackers! So, I'm fairly new to using React-Apollo and Graphql. I currently have a query that looks like this ...

```
query GET_USER($id: Int!) { 
   getUser(id: $id) {
      id
      firstname
      lastname
      pets {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
```

Feeding it into my props...

`const { data: { getUser = [] } } = this.props;`

And trying to map through pets using...

```
{getUser.pets.map(pet =>
    <div>
        {pet.name}
    </div>
 )}
```

After many attempts, I've had no luck in successfully rendering the data. Although, if I console.log(getUser.pets) I get back an array of objects.

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, name: "Ginger", __typename: "Pet", Symbol(id): "Pet:1"}
1:  {id: 2, name: "Marco", __typename: "Pet", Symbol(id): "Pet:2"}
2: {id: 3, name: "Bella", __typename: "Pet", Symbol(id): "Pet:3"}
3: {id: 4, name: "Chiki", __typename: "Pet", Symbol(id): "Pet:4"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Here is the link to the file repo
https://github.com/Jesus369/frendapet/blob/master/src/routes/userpage/UserRoute.js

Any suggestions on how to render the data to the client?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Where are you doing your console.log? Is `getUser` an async function?  Are you storing anything in state?

Comment: At the moment the only error I get back is "Cannot read property map of undefined". getUser is not an async function, and it's using joinMonster to help with fetching the data. Nothing is stored in the state. Using the query provided by gql I'm able to pass the data as props. Console logging is happening below the render() function along with passing the data.

Comment: What is this line doing? `const { data: { getUser = [] } } = this.props;` Should it just be `const { getUser } = this.props;`?

Comment: `getUser` should always be an object, not an array.

Comment: And looking at your query, you set pets to be an object: `pets { id name }` not an array of objects?

Comment: You are approaching the problem in possibly the wrong way. You should not do any logic that deals with data in the `render()` method. That is, you should not be calling functions to fetch data right away in the `render()` method. Furthermore, I wouldn't do that try/catch block you have with stuff about user and email. That should be done in lifecycle methods such as `componentDidMount()`. The method render() expects the data to already be defined somewhere or is in the process of being fetched (done by another method).

Comment: Then, you check with `if (!this.props.data.whatever) { return <div>Loading</div>; }` to return some sort of spinner/loading message if data is not yet defined/ready (you could also use `this.props.data.loading`, I think it is there. Do a `console.log(this.props)` to see what's actually in the object.) If the if block doesn't execute, it goes on to render stuff because data will have been defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help you two! I've tried both methods but haven't had any luck. I finally found a solution though! @Chase DeAnde, I've fixed my getUser and changed it into an object rather than an array, thank you! I ended up passing pets from my UserRoute to my BottomTab as props, and rendered it as so, `pets = []`, now this way I'm able to loop through the pets array. Updated my GitHub to show results